# index and application.ini confusion & few simple questions

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

New to Zend Framework. I been reading and found that whatever mentioned in application.ini is initialized.

**1 - My Question** is if I have mentioned include path for Library in ini than why I need to use include path again in index file like

```
// Include path
set_include_path(
    BASE_PATH . '/library'
);
```

**2 -** in application.ini should I write includePaths.library like APPLICATION_PATH "/../library" OR APPLICATION_PATH "/library". Keeping in mind my index APPLICATION_PATH variable?

**3 -** Why should I  _initView() in BootStarp file. What is the use of that code like

```
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
                'ViewRenderer'
            );
            $viewRenderer->setView($view);
```

**application.ini mentioned**

```
;Include path
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

**Bootstrap**

```
<?php

    class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
    {
        protected function _initView()
        {
            // Initialize view
            $view = new Zend_View();
            $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
            $view->headTitle('My Project');
            $view->env = APPLICATION_ENV;

            // Add it to the ViewRenderer
            $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
                'ViewRenderer'
            );
            $viewRenderer->setView($view);

            // Return it, so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
            return $view;
        }
    }
```

**index**

```
<?php
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'));
define('APPLICATION_PATH', BASE_PATH . '/application');

// Include path
set_include_path(
    BASE_PATH . '/library'
);

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV',
              (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')
                                         : 'production'));

// Zend_Application
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap();
$application->run();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 and 2 are a lingering redundancy from older versions of Zend Framework. You may generally choose one method and stick to it.

Either `index.php`

```
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

or `application.ini`

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

Personally, I favour the former.

Your `Bootstrap.php` file also seems to have a few older ZF habits. The newer application architecture includes a resource plugin for the view. Simply place this into your `application.ini` file

```
resources.view.encoding = "utf-8"
```

and change your bootstrap method to

```
// don't call this _initView as that would overwrite the resource plugin
// of the same name
protected function _initViewHelpers()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view'); // ensure view resource has been configured
    $view = $this->getResource('view');

    $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    $view->headTitle('My Project');
    $view->env = APPLICATION_ENV;
}
```

Comment: you prefer ini for library and initialization. Right?

Comment: For setting the include path, I prefer to use code in the index.php. All other configuration goes in the application config file